# How do I make the eventListener to listen only for that particular element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$ul.on("mouseenter", 'li', function() {
    $("li button").slideDown();
});
```

So I have a li with a button adjacent to it like this:

```
<ul>
<li>Buy Robes<button>Delete</button></li>
<li>Go shopping<button>Delete</button></li>
<li>Buy noodles<button>Delete</button></li>
</ul>
```

But when I hover over any particular li, buttons for all lis is shown. But I want for that particular li I hover on. Like using the this keyword.

```
$ul.on("mouseenter", 'li', function() {
        $(this).$("li button").slideDown();
    });
```

Obviously the above code is wrong, but I want that to work something like this.

Comment: Why are you interested in using invalid HTML? You should expect results to be invalid if you knowingly invalidate your code.

Comment: `<ul>` elements can only contain `<li>` elements, so put your buttons inside the list items and just change the selector to select the button inside the list item. AS written, you say: 'select all the buttons inside the list' instead of 'select the button inside this item'.

Comment: @Utkanos I have done the necessary edits. Sorry for the invalid code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in comments, your HTML is invalid. `button`s are adjecent to the `li`s, but the selector you use focuses on finding the `button`s **inside** the `li`s.

Correct your HTML; put the `button`s inside the `li`s:

```
<ul>
  <li>Buy Robes <button>Delete</button></li>
  <li>Go shopping <button>Delete</button></li>
  <li>Buy noodles <button>Delete</button></li>
</ul>
```

Now your selector `$("li button")` targets the correct elements. But still, there is one more issue. You're showing all the `button`s, irrespective of which `li` was hovered. To correct this, scope your selector with `this`:

```
$ul.on("mouseenter", 'li', function() {
    $(this).find("> button").slideDown();
});
```

This way, only the `button`, whose `li` was hovered, will be shown.